# Testing in ropsten network with truffle.js gives me this error

Tags: metamask, nodejs, ropsten, truffle-migration, infura

root@ubuntu-4gb-nyc3-01:~# truffle migrate --network ropsten
(node:14686) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
(node:14686) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js

After that it exits to root@ubuntu-4gb-nyc3-01:~# 
without running 2_deploy_contracts.js

My truffle.js looks like the following :

```
**var bip39 = require("bip39");
var hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');
var ProviderEngine = require("web3-provider-engine");
var WalletSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/wallet.js');
var Web3Subprovider = require("web3-provider-engine/subproviders/web3.js");
var Web3 = require("web3");
// Get our mnemonic and create an hdwallet
var mnemonic = "twelve words we can find in metamask settings reveal seed words blabla";
var hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));
// Get the first account using the standard hd path.
var wallet_hdpath = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/";
var wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(wallet_hdpath + "0").getWallet();
var address = "0x" + wallet.getAddress().toString("hex");
console.log(address);
var providerUrl = "https://ropsten.infura.io/mytoken";
var engine = new ProviderEngine();
engine.addProvider(new WalletSubprovider(wallet, {}));
engine.addProvider(new Web3Subprovider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerUrl)));
engine.start(); // Required by the provider engine.
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      network_id: 3,    // Official ropsten network id
      provider: engine, // Use our custom provider
      from: address,     // Use the address we derived
      gas: 3000000
    }
  },
  rpc: {
    // Use the default host and port when not using ropsten
    host: "my-server-ip-goes-here",
    port: 8545
  }
  };**
```

Where will I find this.provider.sendAsync function?

I m using node : v8.2.1
and Ubuntu 16.04

I m really stuck with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. It was solved after I installed the old version of the npm libralies. I don't think this is the ideal solution.

```
$ npm install ethereumjs-wallet bip39 web3-provider-engine@8.6.1 web3@0.18.4 zeppelin-solidity --save
```

Answer (score 0):

did you changed this value of var mnemonic = "twelve words we can find in metamask settings reveal seed words blabla"; to your phrase METAMASK

Comment: okay I see. do I have to change the mnemonics? you mean I have to use actual metamask chrome extension and then get the value from there? I m sorry. I got confused.

Comment: yes, it will be creat your contarct by first address eth on metamask

Comment: I created a 12 word mnemonic from metamask plugin from chrome. and then tried to deploy the conract in ropsten again after updating the truffle.js with the new mnemonic. Again the same error :UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
(node:22993) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.